# How to typeset itemized matrices in math display mode

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How to typeset the two matrices which are labeled with (1) and (2) on the same line, as shown below? I tried

1. Placing `align, pmatrix` inside a `minipage` environment, but then the two matrices are in two different lines.
2. Placing two `pmatrix` in a single `equation` environment, but then the labels "(1)" and "(2)" are not aligned correctly -- they are center aligned instead of top aligned as desired.

I guess I will need some manual box settings to get desired outputs, but it's beyond my knowledge. [image]

The code I am currently using now is pasted below:

```
 $$(1)\; A = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 & 4 \\
        4 & -7 & 8 \\
        6 & -7 & 7 
    \end{pmatrix*}; \quad (2)\; A = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        0 & -2 & 3 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & -1 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix*}.$$
```

Comment: It is very easy, e.g. with a `\vphantom`, but not many want to punch in the matrices from scratch. Please post the code that produces the above output.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[ \newcommand{\FirstMat}{\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 & 4 \\
        4 & -7 & 8 \\
        6 & -7 & 7 
    \end{pmatrix*}}
\begin{array}{c}
(1) \\ \vphantom{\FirstMat}\\
\end{array} 
\begin{array}{c}
A =\FirstMat\;,\\
    \vphantom{X}\\
\end{array} 
\quad    
\begin{array}{c}
(2) \\ \vphantom{\FirstMat}\\
\end{array} 
\begin{array}{c}
A = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        0 & -2 & 3 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & -1 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix*}\;.\\
\end{array}    
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great technique! Learned something very useful.